# How to get the reference to all Entity Framework EntityTypeConfiguration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working with Entity Framework 6 and ASP.NET and I come across this problem:

suppose I have these 2 entity mappings configured on 2 class model A,B:
    class A { string property1 { get; set }, string property2 {get; set} }
    class B { string property1 { get; set }, string property2 {get; set} }

```
public class AConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<A> {
    ToTable("TableA");
    Property( x => x.propperty1 ).maxLength(10).HasColumnName("Column1");
    Property( x => x.property2 ).maxLength(10).HasColumnName("Column2");
}

public class BConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<B> {
    ToTable("TableB");
    Property( x => x.propperty1 ).maxLength(10).HasColumnName("Column1");
    Property( x => x.property2 ).maxLength(10).HasColumnName("Column2");
}
```

Assume I already finished configuring EF for my projects and reading and writing to DB works perfectly.

Now my question is: Is there a way to retrieve all the properties that we configured above in a dictionary format ?
For example:

```
//This would return a dictionary that looks somehow like this:
/* {
     "TableA": { 
                   property1: { 
                                  maxLength: 10
                              }
                   property2: {
                                  maxLength: 10
                   }
               },
     "TableB": {
                   property1: { 
                                  maxLength: 10
                              }
                   property2: {
                                  maxLength: 10
                   }
                }
    }

*/
// I want to look for some method similar to this
var allEntityTypeConfiguration = entityFrameworkConfig.getAllEntityTypeConfiguration()
```

After All, all I want to retrieve is the list of all properties defined in EntityTypeConfiguration and its configuration ( e.x: maxLength 10, or something like that)

I googled this problem for a while but still did not find any methods provided by EF. Is there a workaround if possible ?

Comment: hey @Son Do, when you say all properties means.. you want retrieve all the **table name** and **column names ** with **data types** which are existing in EF right ?

Comment: Hi, you r correct

Comment: please check below solution and if you find it as useful, please accept it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

**Working code**

```
     using (var dbContext = new YourDBEntities())
        {
            var metadata = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;

            var tables = metadata.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.SSpace)
                .GetItems<EntityContainer>()
                .Single()
                .BaseEntitySets
                .OfType<EntitySet>()
                .Where(s => !s.MetadataProperties.Contains("Type")
                || s.MetadataProperties["Type"].ToString() == "Tables");

           //tables will be having list of table in your entity framework

            foreach (EntitySet table in tables) //foreach on tables list
            {
                //if you need table name
                var tableName = table.MetadataProperties.Contains("Table")
                    && table.MetadataProperties["Table"].Value != null
                    ? table.MetadataProperties["Table"].Value.ToString()
                    : table.Name;

               //if you need schema name
                var tableSchema = table.MetadataProperties["Schema"].Value.ToString();

               //Here are the list of complete columns in that table
                var columnDetails = table.ElementType.Members;

                //you can get each column properties from above columns list             
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Let me test it out with my code and I'll get back to you :)